# Active menu with navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please can someone tell what exactly what should I add to this code to highlight the menu of the activated page? I saw lot of things online but they didn't work.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

/* CSS */
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #104e8B;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20%; /* Five links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}


.navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color:  #AA0000;
    color: white;
}

.navbar a:hover {
   background-color: #AA0000;
   color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #10CCCC;
  color: white;
}   
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar" id="Menu">
  <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/research">Research</a>
  <a href="/cv" class="right">CV</a>
  <a href="/blog" class="right">Blog</a>
</div><!-- Menu-->
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that I should add a `script`. Can I add add the `script` to this code or It should be in other file?

This is for example something I add to the `style` content but it does not work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Menu .navbar a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});  
</script>
```

Comment: This script will not load without the addition of a jQuery Library. You can run this in native JavaScript, but it will have to be rewritten for that. If your web server supports Server Side Scripting like PHP or .NET, you can simply had that script add the Class attribute to proper link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you'll need to import JQuery before using its function, by linking its CDN.
2. the idiomatic placement of javascript code is usually at the lower section of the body tag
3. having an id to each of the buttons is better than this.location.pathname, eg, it will not work on jsfiddle since the path generated in jsfiddle is different than the one on the HTML tag

   ```
   <div class="navbar" id="Menu">
     <a id='home' href="/">Home</a>
     <a id='about' href="/about">About</a>
     <a id='research' href="/research">Research</a>
     <a id='cv' href="/cv" class="right">CV</a>
     <a id='blog' href="/blog" class="right">Blog</a>
   </div><!-- Menu-->
   </body>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#research').addClass('active');
   });  
   </script>
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/skwn50dj/

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand  `#research` you meant `#Menu` instead?

Comment: if you look through the html code, i've added extra id to each of the A Tag element. so it would be able to identify on which A it should choose.

Comment: I don't understand. I copy the code but only the research page is activated

Comment: That is because it is set statically in his code. You need a way to dynamically see if the nav is set to the page you are on. Use body ID for this...

Comment: When you copy the code to another page, just point the id to according to the page you on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vanilla JS example.

```js
function detectLocation() {
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  console.log(path);
  var a = document.querySelector("#Menu .active");
  a.className = a.className.replace(/\active\b/g, "");
  var n = document.getElementById('Menu').getElementsByTagName("a");
  var i = 0;
  for (i; i < n.length; i++) {
    console.log(n[i]);
    if (n[i].getAttribute("href") == path) {
      console.log("Hit " + i);
      n[i].className = n[i].className + " active";
    }
  }
}

detectLocation();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #104e8B;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20%;
  /* Five links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #AA0000;
  color: white;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #AA0000;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #10CCCC;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="Menu">
  <a href="/" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="/about">About</a>
  <a href="/research">Research</a>
  <a href="/js" class="test">Test</a>
  <a href="/blog" class="right">Blog</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank  you for your help. But it does not work. I put your code in .js file and add the file to my html file. I also import jQuery in my html file. Did I miss something?

Comment: Don't know. Do you see any errors in your Console. My answer is vanilla JS so would not require jQuery. If you plan to use jQuery framework, can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a dynamic way to do this using the body ID tag to set the class in your active page.

1. The script gets the tags elements, then iterates them through a
       function using `.each()`.
2. We then define the val of the current iterated element using `var
   bodyId =` and `$(this).text()`.
3. Then we define the body tags id value using `$('#' +
   val).attr('id');`
4. Run a conditional to see if the current iterated ID's value is the
   same as the body tags ID's set value, if it is,
       `addClass('active')`.

**NOTE:** In order for this to work, each pages body tag must have an ID tag set to the value of the NAVS corresponding A tags value. This must be exactly the same for this to work. The cool part is it all does this dynamically, you won't need code on each page if you place this in a linked JQuery script file.

You will need to add these ID's to your pages body tags:

```
<body id="Home">
<body id="About">
<body id="Home">
<body id="CV">
<body id="Blog">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $(".navbar a").each(function(value) {
  var bodyId = $(this).text();
  var homeId= $('#' + bodyId).attr('id');
    if (bodyId === homeId) {
      console.log('To test this, Change --> '+ $(this).text() + ' --> Change this in the HTML <body id="' + $(this).text() + '">');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #104e8B;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: none;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  padding: 6px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 20%;
  /* Five links of equal widths */
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #AA0000;
  color: white;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #AA0000;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #10CCCC;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="CV">
  <div class="navbar" id="Menu">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Research</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">CV</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">Blog</a>
  </div>
  <!-- Menu-->
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I have i central file for the menu. So I don't repeat the menu in each page.

Comment: But you have the menu displayed on each page right?

Comment: You have a body tag on each page as well right? If you keep your nav on an includes file it does not matter as it is displayed on the page and parsed into the code so when the user interacts with the code it is set on the page.

Comment: No.  I have a main page for the menu. After the menu, the content of this page is empty and the page activated fill the content of the main page. So may main page have two parts. Many and the page activated.

Comment: Hmm, So you are showing certain parts of the page, when the user clicks on say About, that part is displayed and the rest is hidden? If that is the case, simply take the parent level div for that section and add the ID tag there for the corresponding section. Or you could also take Teeeds code and add a .each() loop to iterate over the clicked buttons a tags and set the static div element call to the element that is selected and change it that way.