# Make a specific tab active on page load based on tab ID/href using an attribute

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I have a jsp page with tabs and can make the first tab active on page load, but I need to make a specific tab active using an attribute that I have passed from a servlet that will equal one of the tab's ID's.

I basically need to change the who 'first's in my code to the attribute selectedtab.

The attribute from the servlet at the top of my jsp (this will be either 'RD' or 'PRODUCTION' etc..) -
`String selectedtab = (String)request.getAttribute("thetab");`

my js -

```
//Default Action
 $(".tab_content").hide(); 
 $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
 $(".tab_content:first").show();
```

the tabs -

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a id="RD" href="#RD">R&D</a></li>
    <li><a href="#PRODUCTION">Production</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ENGINEERING">Engineering</a></li>
    <li><a href="#PROCESS SUPPORT">Process Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ESG">ESG</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab6">Not Confirmed</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="RD" class="tab_content">   
*and so on..*
```

EDIT - 
to try and explain further as requested, I want to try and do something like this

```
var default_id =  "<%=selectedtab%>";

$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("#"+default_id).addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab_content:"+default_id).show(); //Show first tab content
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Active menu with navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312394/active-menu-with-navbar)

Comment: Unfortunately not :-(

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry im unsure of what you mean.. I have included my code and showed what way I need it adapted, is that not an example?